# How to use offline map in skobbler

Tags: ios, objective-c

following the developer support page, I download the offline map using the DEMO app software downloaded with the SDK.
Then I moved the packaged in the right path inside the SKMaps.bundle, PreinstalledMaps\v1 folder.
Now I'm lost, how do I tell the system to use the offline map instead of another one or instead of downloading the map of the current position?

thanks

**UPDATE**

From what I understand, once we set:

```
     [SKMapsService sharedInstance].connectivityMode = SKConnectivityModeOffline;
```

The application will pick up automatically the maps that are present offline, the others will not show details. But as final test I download one city and it works, then I add a second one. In this scenario I still can see the first city but once moved to the second city I don't see any details. Am I missing something?

**UPDATE/2**

Once moved to the real divice I see the details of both the cities.